# Vanilla C++ struct to valid Qt QObject

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qobject

Can someone help me with my problem (it's about C++ and Qt)? I have struct: bunch of field with different types. I want to proxy the object fields, other words, make the struct objects valid QObjects (create getter, setter, signal and Q_PROPERTY for each object field). So how can I create such proxy for any struct? There is actually a lot of structs, so I want to automate process of creation such proxies. Any tools or method how to do such thing?
I tried to make it work, but there is a problem that the programming language does not have proper reflection and you can't create classes based on other classes.

I want to pass C++ object to QML to be able to change it from there, but I didn't get how to make it work.

I don't know how to build such architecture to be able to communicate from QML and vanilla C++ struct object.

Any ideas would be helpful!

P.S. I would like to give additional information on the problem I'm trying to solve.

I have several structs (lets say 100)

```cpp
// fizzbuzz.h
#ifndef FIZZBUZZ_H
#define FIZZBUZZ_H

struct FizzBuzz
{
  int a;
  double b;
  bool c;
};

#endif // FIZZBUZZ_H

// foobar.h
#ifndef FOOBAR_H
#define FOOBAR_H

enum FooBarEnum
{
  FOO = 1,
  BAR = 12
};

struct FooBar
{
  bool k;
  FooBarEnum d;
  double c;
};

#endif // FOOBAR_H
```

and I want to get from given class something like that:

```cpp
class {CLASS_NAME}_QObject : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  
  // there will be as much setters, getters, signals and 
  // property macros as passed object has fields

  // property macro
  Q_PROPERTY({FIELD_TYPE} {FIELD_NAME} READ {FIELD_NAME} WRITE set{CAPITALIZED_FIELD_NAME})
public:
  // constructor
  explicit {CLASS_NAME}_QObject({CLASS_NAME} *object, QObject *parent = nullptr) 
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_object(object) 
  {
  
  }

  // getter
  {FIELD_TYPE} {FIELD_NAME}() const {
    return m_object->{FIELD_NAME};
  }

  // setter
  void set{CAPITALIZED_FIELD_NAME}({FIELD_TYPE} {FIELD_NAME}) {
    m_object->{FIELD_NAME}= {FIELD_NAME};
  }

signals:
  // signal
  void {FIELD_NAME}Changed({FIELD_TYPE} {FIELD_NAME});

private:
  {CLASS_NAME} *m_object;
}
```

Of cause it is not valid C++ code but there is comment to make it more clear.

Does anybody have suggestions how to create something like that? Maybe is it possible to solve this somehow more simple?

Comment: Wrap the C++ struct in a new Qt one and make sure you can convert one to the other.

Comment: How can you do that if Q_OBJECT does not allow you to create template classes?

Comment: And also how would you do field proxying if you just don't have anything to get fields and create them? This is question about how to create completely valid QObject from C++ struct. That what you wrote in the comment have no sense, to be fair.

Comment: I don't know Qt specifically but I have a lot of experience "glueing" together different technologies. I always write my main code as standard C++/static lib (and unit testing that) before going to non-standard C++ libraries. So if you know how to write a Qt object with properties from scratch it should not be to hard to make such a class use the original struct (as a member of reference) and for any setter called on the Qt object you set a value on the original C++ struct, and if needed it is that (internal) C++ struct you forward to the original C++ code.

Comment: Look up model-view or any architecture like that they all say you have to split business logic (the pure C++ bit) from UI code anyway

Comment: As an aside, see if `G_GADGET` is enough for your purpose.